# When using the GET chromeosdevices method, are custom fields returned in the resource returned?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm not optimistic because I don't see any reference to custom fields in the resource page here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/chromeosdevices#resource

but I'm wondering if anyone has experience with this.

In the Google Admin console (Device management->Chrome->Devices-><) there is a section for custom fields. Is there any way to retrieve that using the API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Though not explicitly documented, when I raised an enhancement request, the Google team let me know it is already possible. Response from Google:

Please note that retrieving custom fields for `Chromeosdevices: get` is already possible.

You can verify it by testing with the `Try this API` of [Chromeosdevices: get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/chromeosdevices/get), selecting the option `Show standard parameters` and specifying `fields`.

Indeed, they are there!